# Check if a subscription is still active calling it by name+parameter

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm wondering if there is a way to check at any moment if a global subscription is still active calling it by name and parameter (Since subscriptions are usually cleared when the app has been closed or the device has been restarted).

I know I could do something like:

`MySub = Meteor.subscribe("...` and later check if: `mySub.ready()`

But, since I could have many subscriptions active with different parameters, the only way to associate the subscription parameter with the variable name (`mySub` in the example) is to set the variable name programatically, and that would make my code a little difficult to read.

By the way if I don't care if the subscription is active or not and resubscribe via `Meteor.subscribe` I got redundant subscriptions anytime the template is created. (Checked via `Meteor.default_connection._subscriptions`).  Template based subscriptions are not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The msavin:mongol package shows a list of active subscriptions on the client, I'm not sure how he pulls that off. The traditional pattern is to save the subscription handle. You could put those into an array instead of individual variables.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I could also use a hash with key equal to subscription parameter and the handle as value.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Or create a client side collection to store the data, then you don't need to hash.